# How to implement SP 2010 visual web part in MOSS 2007 site?

Tags: sharepoint-2007, sharepoint-2010, web-parts

I have created a Visual web part for SP2010 site, What I need is to implement it into  MOSS 2007 site.

Does MOSS2007 support visual web part,and how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont see VS 2010 Support Visual WebPart for 2007, but still you can develop a web part using 2010 (not using any of 2010 Feature) and after you completed the development you can package it manually to be deployed to 2007. Yeah its a extra step. Or you can see how [smartpart](http://smartpart.codeplex.com/) works. Smartpart is nothing but similar concept in 2007 World.